# Rolling/moving regressions in R

Tags: r, dplyr, quantmod, magrittr

I am working on the following data in R:

```
# Getting stock data
library(quantmod)
tickers <- c("ASC.OL",  "AFG.OL",   "AKA.OL",   "AKER.OL",  "AKERBP.OL",    "AKSO.OL",  "AKVA.OL",  "AMSC.OL",  "APP.OL",   "AQUA.OL",  "ARCHER.OL",    "ARCUS.OL", "AFK.OL",   "ASETEK.OL",    "ATEA.OL",  "ATLA-NOK.OL",  "AURG.OL",  "AUSS.OL",  "AVANCE.OL",    "AVM.OL",   "AXA.OL",   "B2H.OL",   "BAKKA.OL", "BEL.OL",   "BERGEN.OL",    "BGBIO.OL", "BIOTEC.OL",    "BON.OL",   "BOR.OL",   "BRG.OL",   "BOUVET.OL",    "BWLPG.OL", "BWO.OL",   "BMA.OL",   "COV.OL",   "CXENSE.OL",    "DAT.OL",   "DESSC.OL", "DNB.OL",   "DNO.OL",   "DOF.OL",   "EIOF.OL",  "EKO.OL",   "EMGS.OL",  "EMAS.OL",  "ENTRA.OL", "EPR.OL",   "FAR.OL",   "FOE.OL",   "FRO.OL",   "FUNCOM.OL",    "GIG.OL",   "RISH.OL",  "GJF.OL",   "GOGL.OL",  "GOD.OL",   "GSF.OL",   "GYL.OL",   "HNA.OL",   "HNB.OL",   "HAVI.OL",  "HYARD.OL", "HELG.OL",  "HEX.OL",   "HIDDN.OL", "HLNG.OL",  "HSPG.OL",  "IMSK.OL",  "IDEX.OL",  "INC.OL",   "ISSG.OL",  "INSR.OL",  "IOX.OL",   "ITX.OL",   "ITE.OL",   "JIN.OL",   "JAEREN.OL",    "KID.OL",   "KIT.OL",   "KOA.OL",   "KOG.OL",   "KVAER.OL", "LSG.OL",   "LINK.OL",  "MHG.OL",   "MEDI.OL",  "MELG.OL",  "MULTI.OL", "NAPA.OL",  "NAVA.OL",  "NEL.OL",   "NEXT.OL",  "NGT.OL",   "NANO.OL",  "NOD.OL",   "NHY.OL",   "NSG.OL",   "NRS.OL",   "NAS.OL",   "NOR.OL",   "NOFI.OL",  "NPRO.OL",  "NRC.OL",   "NTS.OL",   "OCY.OL",   "OTS.OL",   "ODL.OL",   "ODF.OL",   "ODFB.OL",  "OLT.OL",   "OPERA.OL", "ORK.OL",   "PEN.OL",   "PARB.OL",  "PGS.OL",   "PDR.OL",   "PHO.OL",   "PLCS.OL",  "POL.OL",   "PRS.OL",   "PROTCT.OL",    "QFR.OL",   "QEC.OL",   "RAKP.OL",  "REACH.OL", "REC.OL",   "RENO.OL",  "SDSD.OL",  "SAFE.OL",  "SALM.OL",  "SADG.OL",  "SAS-NOK.OL",   "SSO.OL",   "SCHA.OL",  "SCHB.OL",  "SBX.OL",   "SDRL.OL",  "SBO.OL",   "SEVDR.OL", "SEVAN.OL", "SIOFF.OL", "SKBN.OL",  "SKI.OL",   "SKUE.OL",  "SOLON.OL", "SOFF.OL",  "SOFFB.OL", "SOLV.OL",  "SONG.OL",  "SBVG.OL",  "NONG.OL",  "RING.OL",  "MING.OL",  "SRBANK.OL",    "SOAG.OL",  "MORG.OL",  "SOR.OL",   "SVEG.OL",  "SPOG.OL",  "SPU.OL",   "STL.OL",   "SNI.OL",   "STB.OL",   "STORM.OL", "STRONG.OL",    "SUBC.OL",  "TIL.OL",   "TRVX.OL",  "TEAM.OL",  "TECH.OL",  "TEL.OL",   "TGS.OL",   "SSC.OL",   "THIN.OL",  "TOM.OL",   "TOTG.OL",  "TRE.OL",   "TTS.OL",   "VEI.OL",   "VVL.OL",   "WWL.OL",   "WEIFA.OL", "WRL.OL",   "WWI.OL",   "WWIB.OL",  "WILS.OL",  "XXL.OL",   "YAR.OL",   "ZAL.OL")
dataEnv <- new.env()
out <- sapply(tickers, function(s) tryCatch({ getSymbols(s , env = dataEnv) }, error = function(e) NA))
plist <- eapply(dataEnv, Ad)
pframe <- do.call(merge, plist)
names(pframe) <- gsub(".Adjusted", "", names(pframe))
names(pframe) <- gsub(".X", "", names(pframe))
pframe <- log(pframe)
pframe <- diff(pframe, lag = 1)
pframe<-t(pframe)
library(reshape2)
pframe<- melt(pframe)
library(data.table)
setnames(pframe, old=c("Var1","Var2", "value"), new=c("Ticker", "Date", "Returns"))

# Getting index data
index <- c("^GSPC")
dataEnv1 <- new.env()
out1 <- sapply(index, function(s) tryCatch({ getSymbols(s , env = dataEnv1) }, error = function(e) NA))
index <- eapply(dataEnv1, Ad)
index <- do.call(merge, index)
names(index) <- gsub(".Adjusted", "", names(index))
names(index) <- gsub(".X", "", names(index))
index <- log(index)
index <- diff(index, lag = 1)
index<-t(index)
index<- melt(index)
library(data.table)
setnames(index, old=c("Var1","Var2", "value"), new=c("Index", "Date", "Index_Returns"))

# Getting curr data
curr <- c("NOK=X")
dataEnv1 <- new.env()
out1 <- sapply(curr, function(s) tryCatch({ getSymbols(s , env = dataEnv1) }, error = function(e) NA))
curr <- eapply(dataEnv1, Ad)
curr <- do.call(merge, curr)
names(curr) <- gsub(".Adjusted", "", names(curr))
names(curr) <- gsub(".X", "", names(curr))
curr <- log(curr)
curr <- diff(curr, lag = 1)
curr<-t(curr)
curr<- melt(curr)
library(data.table)
setnames(curr, old=c("Var1","Var2", "value"), new=c("NOK", "Date", "NOK_Returns"))

NOK_index <- merge(index, curr, by="Date")
NOK_index$Index <- NULL
NOK_index$NOK <- NULL

Final <- merge(pframe, NOK_index, by="Date")
Final <- na.omit(Final)
```

I am trying to run moving/rolling time-series regressions by group, in the dataset called `Final`. The group-id is the variable called `Ticker`. The window I want is to be based on at least 120 observations at most 240. I want to regress `Return` on `Market_ret`. Put differently for each day I want to have one beta, that is regressed using the previous 120 to 240 observations, as available. Currently working on the regression code below, trying to make the regressions rolling. Any suggestion?

```
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)   
library(broom)
## Fit models
fitted_model <- Final %>% group_by(Ticker) %>% do(tidy(lm(Returns ~ Index_Returns + NOK_Returns, data = .)))
```

Final appears as the following:

```
Date      Ticker       Returns Index_Returns   NOK_Returns
316    2007-01-04      NRC.OL -0.0374163851  1.227532e-03  8.821413e-03
382    2007-01-05      NRC.OL  0.0087596430 -6.103168e-03  6.781505e-03
573    2007-01-08      NRC.OL  0.0454647126  2.217857e-03 -3.668920e-03
930    2007-01-09      NRC.OL -0.0111738655 -5.168099e-04  3.024291e-03
952    2007-01-10      NRC.OL -0.0227294199  1.938472e-03  1.341967e-02
1290   2007-01-11      NRC.OL -0.0086585150  6.319861e-03  4.891726e-03
1333   2007-01-12      NRC.OL  0.0028945097  4.841427e-03 -4.783106e-03
1520   2007-01-16      NRC.OL -0.0052913027  8.174609e-04  1.476038e-03
1803   2007-01-17      NRC.OL -0.0053194495 -8.943372e-04 -1.382750e-03
1923   2007-01-18      NRC.OL  0.0079686006 -2.975161e-03  4.993729e-03
2232   2007-01-19      NRC.OL  0.0439938878  2.891282e-03 -2.044104e-03
```

I have  multiple tickers.

Comment: What does your `"Final"` data look like?

Comment: Just edited the post with a sample of the data

Comment: Have you tried with ```tidyquant``` package? It gives you the rolling options like in the package ```zoo``` but in the ```tidyverse``` logic. It Is very useful